# Octave - Creating a sequence of odd numbers between 1 and 10 separated by zeros

Tags: matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

Without explicitly typing in the values, and using only a single line of code (no semicolons!), I am trying to write a code that creates the following series of numbers, and outputs it to screen:

a= 1 0 3 0 5 0 7 0 9 0

Here's my best attempt to achieve this,

```
a= [1:10].*[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

This produces and displays the right result, but I still need a shorter way since I am typing in the values of the second matrix ([1 0 1 0 1 0...]).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`repmat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Special-Utility-Matrices.html) to duplicate the `[1,0]` array 5 times for a total of 10 elements.  As such, try doing:

```
a = [1:10].*repmat([1 0], 1, 5)

a =

 1     0     3     0     5     0     7     0     9     0
```

Alternatively, you can do this with pure indexing:

```
a([1:2:9 10]) = [1:2:9 0]

a =

 1     0     3     0     5     0     7     0     9     0
```

---

The trick with the second piece of code is that when you dynamically allocate a variable this way, MATLAB / Octave fills whatever missing values you didn't index with zeroes.  As such, we are going to define values in locations 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 to be exactly 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.  However, doing this by itself will create a 9 element array.  To make this 10 elements, I have to supply an additional index of 10, and then on the right side of the expression, I have to add a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Or create a

```
a = 1:10;
```

and then set elements at even positions to 0

```
a(2:2:10) = 0
a =

   1   0   3   0   5   0   7   0   9   0
```

---

EDIT (thanks to rayryeng for pointing out the rule !)

And a one liner:

```
a = (1:10) .* (mod(1:10, 2) != 0)
a =

   1   0   3   0   5   0   7   0   9   0
```

Comment: Cool!  That works too.  +1.  However, I think the OP wanted a single command.  This technically would be two, but still good use of using the even positions of the array though.

Comment: @rayryeng Oh, I overlooked the "only a single line of code" part. Now I understand why your answer seemed so overly clever !

Comment: No worries :) For readability, I would choose your code over mine.  The single line constraint is a bit annoying, but it was the only thing that I could think of other than using `repmat`.  Still gave you a +1 anyway as I didn't consider zeroing out the even entries!

Comment: Thanks! I added a one-liner using the even properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

`kron( [1:2:10] , [1 0])`

The reason I like it better is because you can modify the upper limit (10) in a single location in the line.

In case you are new to `kron`, what it does is that it takes two matrices `A` and `B`, and returns a big matrix that looks like this:

```
[ A(1,1)*B  A(1,2)*B ... ]
[ A(2,1)*B  A(2,2)*B ... ]
[ ...       ...      ... ]
```